# Python Flask Get URL Parameters with spaces

Tags: python, flask

My Javascript post url is as shown below with %20 in between i.e. spaces, when I'm trying to access this URL with Flask the search variable is shown as type None.

Am I parsing the url parameter cmpname correctly inside showMapMArker() function, Not sure about it.

```
POST /getLatLong/Ogden%20UT%20844
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/getLatLong/<cmpname>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def showMapMarker(cmpname):
    # print("Inside ShowMarker")
    search = request.args.get(cmpname)

//do something with search string

return jsonify(search)
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
              var cmpCanName = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value;
              var cmpCanAddress = document.getElementById("autocompletetwo").value;

          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.open("POST", "/getLatLong/"+cmpCanAddress, true);
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
          xhttp.send();
          var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

`showMapMarker(cmpname)` will be called with `cmpname` set to the value given in the route `'/getLatLong/<cmpname>'`. You then use that value for a lookup in the request arguments, which will result in `None` if the request has no such argument. So to not return None, the request URL would have to look like this:

```
http://example.com/getLatLong/ham?ham=spam
```

Now `search` would be the string `spam`, `ham` can be freely chosen by the caller. I don't think that is what you intended, you probably just want to use the `cmpname` argument as passed to the function.

Comment: I'm getting a None Type for the search variable, Not sure why cmpname value is not fetched.

Comment: You don't need to, it's passed to the function by the framework. Just try `search = cmpname`, that should be it. Your request  doesn't seem to have either arguments or post data.